# Microsoft SQL Server 2012から2016へのアップグレードについて

Tags: sql-server

表題の件について質問です。

SQL Server 2012から2016へアップグレードしたいのですが、この場合、まず2012の方からバックアップを取ってリストア、リカバリする必要があるでしょうか？

それともパッチなりを当ててそのままバージョンアップすることなど可能なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[サポートされているバージョンとエディションのアップグレード (SQL Server 2016)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades?view=sql-server-2016) を確認してください。問題が無ければ[インプレースアップグレード](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server-using-the-installation-wizard-setup?view=sql-server-2016)可能です。